# Difficulties converting 8-bit greyscale .BMP images to 1-bit .BMP Images

Tags: c, bmp

I'm looking for a way to convert a BMP image of 256 grey levels to a 1-bit BMP image. The conversion rule is that the bit should be 0 for grey levels from 0 - 127, and 1 from 128 - 255. So far I have attempted to make a program in C. The problem is even though I changed the bits per pixel in the information header to 1 BBP, the output is a black image (I'm using Lena as the input file btw) as if the colour depth is still 8-bit (while in Properties it says 1-bit).

I tried to open the BMP file in a hex editor and saw that the pixel data had been changed to 0 and 1 as expected and the headers of the input and output files were the same except the colour depth. Am I missing anything? What changes do I need to make for the image to show what is expected?
[image: link]

Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#pragma pack(1)     //avoid padding in a struct    

typedef uint8_t  BYTE;
typedef uint32_t DWORD;
typedef int32_t  LONG;
typedef uint16_t WORD;

typedef struct 
{
    WORD Signature;
    DWORD fSize;
    WORD fReserved_1;
    WORD fReserved_2;
    DWORD fOffset;
} BITMAP_HEADER;

typedef struct 
{
    DWORD Size;
    LONG  Width;
    LONG  Height;
    WORD  Planes;
    WORD  BitsPerPixel;
    DWORD Compression;
    DWORD imgSize;
    LONG  ResX;
    LONG  ResY;
    DWORD Color;
    DWORD ImpColor;
} INFO_HEADER;

typedef struct
{
    BYTE rgbtBlue;    //since I'm only dealing with 8-bit colour depth 
                      //so only one value is needed I guess?
    // BYTE rgbtGreen;
    // BYTE rgbtRed;
} RGBTRIPLE;

void BinaryConvert(DWORD height, DWORD width, RGBTRIPLE img[height][width]);

int main()
{
    FILE* fp, *cp;
    fp = fopen("Resources/test.bmp", "rb");     //bmp is binary file, therefore use "rb" permission
    cp = fopen("Resources/output.bmp", "wb");

    BITMAP_HEADER fHeader;
    INFO_HEADER   fInfo;
    
    //read headers
    fread(&fHeader, sizeof(BITMAP_HEADER), 1, fp);
    fread(&fInfo, sizeof(INFO_HEADER), 1, fp);

    int width = fInfo.Width;
    int height = fInfo.Height;

    int padding = (4 - (width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;
    
    RGBTRIPLE (*image)[width] = calloc(height, width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));

    //read pixel data
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        fread(image[i], sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), width, fp);
        fseek(fp, padding,  SEEK_CUR);      //skip over padding
    }

    //coonvert grey levels into 0 and 1
    BinaryConvert(height, width, image);

    //modify file header
    fInfo.noBitsPerPixel = 1;

    //write headers into output file
    fseek(cp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(&fHeader, sizeof(BITMAP_HEADER), 1, cp);
    fwrite(&fInfo, sizeof(INFO_HEADER), 1, cp);
  
    //write pixel data into output file
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
       fwrite(image[i], sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), width, cp);
       for (int k = 0; k < padding; k++)
       {
           fputc(0x00, cp);
       }
    }

    fclose(cp);
    fclose(fp);   
}
   
void BinaryConvert(DWORD height, DWORD width, RGBTRIPLE img[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            if (img[i][j].rgbtBlue <= 127 && img[i][j].rgbtBlue >=0)
            {
                img[i][j].rgbtBlue = 0;
            }
            else if (img[i][j].rgbtBlue <= 255 && img[i][j].rgbtBlue >= 128)
                img[i][j].rgbtBlue = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

[Input file (lena.bmp). (257 KB)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5fTl.jpg)

[Result from program (257 KB)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z8M2.jpg)

Comment: Please include a small example input file as text into your [mre]. (I.e. not only as picture of text.) Same for the example failure output. Ideally add a manually (or by picture editor) created desired result.

Comment: @Yunosch Thanks for the suggestion. I have edited the post.

Comment: I would imagine an 1-bpp image to tightly pack 8 pixels into a byte...

Comment: You only reduce the number of possible values in the 8 bits to 2 but you still use 8 bits per pixel.

Comment: If you only deal with 8 bits per pixel, you should not use a struct called `RGBTRIPLE`. That is confusing any reader. Also the 8 bits are not the value for blue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 255 instead of 1. That is the color for white

Comment: How exactly do you expect to store `255` in a **1-bit**-per-pixel image?

Comment: It is in the pallete. The pallete will have two entries with values `0x00` and `0xff` for black and white. The bits will be translated to these values upon display.

Comment: The pallete entries are `RGBTRIPLE`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie> this should be read in the context of the question. The OP uses `0` and `1` byte for each pixel. Telling him to use `255` instead is incorrect. He should use 1 bit per pixel. And yes, store a palette - but one thing at a time - point is this answer sends the OP on a wrong way.